# strncpy does not store characters properly C

Tags: c, arrays, char, truncate, strncpy

Basically, I use `strncpy` to truncate the characters if it is greater than the character array size.

So, I have the following variables and methods.

```
char studentName[6];
char colour[5];
char music[7];

strcpy(this->studentName, "null");
strcpy(this->colour, "null");
strcpy(this->music, "null"):

void setName (char* studentName)
{
 strncpy(this->studentName, studentName, 6);
 this->studentName[6] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}

void setColour (char* colour)
{
 strncpy(this->colour, colour, 5);
 this->colour[5] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}

void setMusic (char* music)
{
 strncpy(this->music, music, 7);
 this->music[7] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}
```

So, if I set the student name to `Jackson`, it will truncate to `Jackso`, however, my `colour` variable will be blank and my `music` variable will be `null`.

Also, if I try...

```
void setName (char* studentName)
{
  strncpy(this->studentName, studentName, 6);
  this->studentName[6-1] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}

void setColour (char* colour)
{
 strncpy(this->colour, colour, 5);
 this->colour[5-1] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}

void setMusic (char* music)
{
 strncpy(this->music, music, 7);
 this->music[7-1] = '\0'; // SET LAST TO NULL POINTER
}
```

and I set the student name to `Jackson` I get something like `Jacksonull`. It adds `null` to the end

Comment: When you declare `studentName[6]`, valid indicies are `[0]` to `[5]`.  So setting a `'\0'` at position `[6]` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @abelenky, so even if `this->studentName[5] = '\0'`, why does it still add the `null` value that was previously in this array, e.g. `Jacksonull`

Comment: Since you have not shown us Where/When/How the functions `setName`, `setColour` and `setMusic` are called, it is very difficult to say.  Post more code, plz.

Comment: The above comment is correct the positions are 0 indexed so studentName[6] is the seventh member of the 6 member studentName array. More than likely it is actually the first member of the colour array. Also setting your default string values to "null" is very confusing as null is used to refer to 0 pointer.

Comment: @MatthewVCarey Thanks, so how do I set the last character to be the terminating character?

Comment: Re. the update "Jacksonull" you have a bug somewhere else in your code that you didn't post, or you didn't actually put the right numbers in to these expressions.  (using `strncpy` is a terrible idea all around)

Comment: The good news is: avoid `strncpy()` it is terrible, useless, etc. Just avoid it.

Comment: My rant on the perils of `strncpy`: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Answer (score 1):

Here (assumes Linux platform. You might have to fetch strlcpy implementation if your on Windows, not sure.)

```
#include <bsd/string.h>

char studentName[6]; /* Good to know: Globals are initialized to zero */
char colour[5];
char music[7];

/* Pretty useless function since a single strlcpy call is enough */
static size_t setX(char *buf, size_t buflen, const char *new_val) {
    return strlcpy(buf, new_val, buflen);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setX(studentName, 6, "Peter");  /* Please read man page and check return value */
}
```

Now `strlcpy` guarantees NUL termination as long as length argument is >0.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `sizeof()` instead of raw numbers. It allows you to change array's sizes without touching your code.

You first copy `sizeof(array)-1` symbols and then set the last symbol which is of index `sizeof(array)-1` (because indexing starts from 0) to `'\0'`.

Your code edited would look like this:

```
char studentName[6];
char colour[5];
char music[7];

strcpy(this->studentName, "null");
strcpy(this->colour, "null");
strcpy(this->music, "null"):

void setName (char* studentName)
{
 strncpy(this->studentName, studentName, sizeof(this->studentName)-1); // Copy n-1 chars
 this->studentName[sizeof(this->studentName)-1] = '\0'; // n is set to null symbol
}

void setColour (char* colour)
{
 strncpy(this->colour, colour, sizeof(this->color)-1);
 this->colour[sizeof(this->color)-1] = '\0'; 
}

void setMusic (char* music)
{
 strncpy(this->music, music, sizeof(this->music)-1);
 this->music[sizeof(this->music)-1] = '\0'; 
}
```

Comment: And please don't call `'\0'` a "null pointer", it's just the integer 0. The comments here are both useless and wrong.

Comment: "NULL POINTER" should ready "null byte"  (it's not a pointer)

Comment: The `sizeof` expressions need to be `this->studentName` etc.

Comment: I have tried this, and it adds `null` to the end. I don't know why, but I don't think it is overwriting the previous value in the array

Comment: Sorry, the comments were copied from the original question.

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas, why do you copy `sizeof()-1`?

Comment: @StuUser to leave the last byte for `'\0'`.

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas, but I declared `studentName` as size `6`, so it will copy `5` characters?

Comment: @StuUser Well, yes. The last "slot" is for null character in null-terminated strings. You could copy `6` characters, but then you would have to set the `7`th "slot" into `'\0'` and that would be trespassing array bounds.

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas, I see, thanks. I meant for `strncpy(this->music, music, sizeof(this->music)-1)`, you are copying 6 characters instead of 7. I thought you had to copy the 7 characters

Comment: @StuUser No problems. If my answer helped you, please mark it as an answer to this question. :)

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas, so a `char music[7]` is really an array of `6` plus the `\0` terminating character? Am I right?

Comment: @StuUser If used as a null-terminated string then yes, that is correct.

Comment: @StuUser No, `char music[7]` is an array of size `7`. Then you are free to put "whatever" values you want into these array members. If it's to be treated as a string, _some_ array member must contain a NUL terminator character. So writing "Hi" to the array `a` will look like: `a[0]='H'; a[1]='i'; a[2]='\0';`. `a` can be an array of size `5` for instance, then `a[3]` and `a[4]` can contain whatever for string functions, since those won't read past the `\0`.

Comment: @StuUser Please use `strlcpy` or equivalent since it's guaranteeing NUL termination and takes the actual buffer size, no more `sizeof(x)-1` arguments, which makes your case much easier.